# bootstrap datetimepicker shows two calendars.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am using [Bootstrap datetime picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and when i implement it to a input it shows two calendar instead of one.

```
$('.endtime,.starttime').datetimepicker({pick12HourFormat: false,pickDate: true, format: 'HH:mm'});
```

[image]

Comment: Well you told it to: `$('.endtime,.starttime')`

Comment: well i try it sep too but same result.

Comment: Show your complete code for know more.